How can I set a description(about me) of the bot directly from the code?
I'm using Discord.Net (C#)
I've tried different methods myself, but none of them worked.
I want the bot to change its description(about me) to what is written in the code when it starts.
In the description(about me), I want to specify the version of my bot. My version is set to a public variable.

Typically this is done by setting the "discord game" after the bot has started. It's not really well named, so I get why it's hard to find.

await client.StartAsync();

string version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().Version?.ToString(3);
await client.SetGameAsync($"v{version}", "", ActivityType.Playing);

